# Titanium : Avoiding saved images to be displayed in gallery

Tags: image, file, filesystems, save, titanium

I am using titanium to capture images ( from camera and gallery for both iphone and android ) and i am saving them as jpg's in sd card using file.write();

But i dont want them to be shown in gallery/photogallery for security purposes.

Is there any way to do it ...

Thanks

Comment: what if none of the answers is correct .??

Comment: add a bounty (you cant just yet since you have little karma). Perhaps close the question, since it didn't help you. Or answer yourself, if you found the solution.

Comment: Also, sometimes the answer can be correct, even if you don't agree with it, or is against some weird specifications.

Comment: Hello please help me by post the code for saving image in android gallery taken by camera. I have a problem in saving this in android but have done it in iOS. Please Help me.. Will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `var folder = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'DocImages');

// creating a new folder if it doesnt exist

if (!folder.exists()) {
 folder.createDirectory();
 }

      
imgFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/Docimages/', filenameWithExtension);

// writing image to file
      

imgFile.write(imageVar); 

// where imageVar is the image taken by camera `

Comment: sorry about the mess .. couldnt figure out how to write code properly in comments .. and very busy ... :(

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that, is not to store them there, but keeping them in the app. But even then, if someone really wants it, he can get the photos out of there too.

Note: on iPhone you of course don't have a SD card. When you explicitly say you store it to the gallery on iPhone it will show up in the photo galleries app. Otherwise, it won't.